# Getting unique values using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF and have a context from which I can get a collection of Item objects using _inventoryContext.Items.  Now, these item objects have a string value called Carrier.  Let's say there are 5 items in Items collection and they have these Carrier values:

```
"A", "A", "B", "C", "C"
```

How do I use _inventoryContext.Items to get back the unique carrier values?

```
"A", "B", "C"
```

Note that

```
var carriers = _inventoryContext.Items.Select(i => i.Carrier).Distinct();
```

does not work; I get "The method 'Distinct' is not supported" with no inner exception.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express. `Items` is a [`DataServiceQuery<Item>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646677.aspx) and its `Carrier` property is a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example should work, but here is another way you can try

```
List<string> carriers = _inventoryContext.Items.GroupBy(i => i.Carrier)
                                               .Select(i => i.Key)
                                               .ToList();
```